# -bash: _fzf_orig_completion_g++: bad substitution in Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, 64-bit, windows-8.1

When I open my Cygwin terminal, it shows the following at the top of window:

`-bash: _fzf_orig_completion_g++: bad substitution`

Eventhough it does not affect my jobs, but I want to avoid it.

Suggestions please.

Thanks!

Comment: have you messed your .bashrc or .bash_profile ?

Comment: I did not do anything there but updated cygwin :P

Comment: Saw this on new computer install yesterday. I just removed fzf since I didn't need it.

Comment: @dubnde Would you please elaborate?

Comment: I mean I just uninstalled fzf as I did not need it.

Answer (score 8):

To be precise, edit file C:\cygwin64\etc\bash_completion.d\zzz-fzf. Locate the function `_fzf_defc()` and add the following lines:

```
 cmd="${cmd//+/_}"
 cmd="${cmd//-/_}"
```

between the lines `opts="$3"` and `orig_var="_fzf_orig_completion_$cmd"`

Worked for me. Regards.

Answer (score 3):

cygwin64， modify /etc/bash_completion_d/zzz-fzf, then it does work.

```
 cmd="$1"
 func="$2"
 opts="$3"
 cmd="${cmd//+/_}"
 cmd="${cmd//-/_}"
 orig_var="_fzf_orig_completion_$cmd"
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this is a known issue. An issue on the github page for fzf posted on [Jan 16, 2017](https://github.com/me-and/Cygwin-fzf/issues/3) talks about it. The poster there posits the problem is the following,

> the way i read all this is the reason for the error is the presence of the terminal part of the string, "...g++", as the ..++ part comprises illegal characters in a name

The above link references [another similar issue posted on Sept 24, 2016](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf/issues/668) where the author responded on Jan 11th,

> The support for Cygwin was discontinued since 0.9.0 due to the portability issue of ncurses library. But I'm working on a new renderer that does not depend on ncurses (#782), and it might be possible that we can make the latest fzf work on Cygwin again (#794). I'll let you know if it works out.

The easiest way to remove the bad substitution error that you are getting would be, as @dubnde posted in the comments and I can verify as well, to uninstall fzf and its related packages until the support is worked out for cygwin.